# Using -apple-system for monospace and serif

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I know that `-apple-system` defaults to San Francisco on macOS and iOS, but what defaults to SF Mono and New York (the default serif font for Apple products)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Starting from Safari 13.1, they added font family names for system fonts:

- `ui-monospace` — SF Mono
- `ui-serif` — New York
- `ui-sans-serif` — San Francisco (same as `system-ui` and `-apple-system`)

See the [blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/10247/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13-1/).

The CSS I use to get the system monospace on most platforms is as follows:

```css
code {
  font-family: 'SF Mono', SFMono-Regular, ui-monospace,
    'DejaVu Sans Mono', Menlo, Consolas, monospace;
}
```

The first three are SF Mono, then the Bitstream Vera-derived fonts on Linux (DejaVu) and Mac (Menlo), closing with whatever works on Windows (Consolas).